# Javascript array.filter() element being skipped

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I am trying to delete out the common elements in arguments given and
create a final array with unique elements.
In the below example my final array is giving me [1,3,4,5] instead of [1,4,5].
  I did the debug and the one of element (3) is not going through the loop.
After element (2) it's skipping to element (4). I am confused why is this happening? Anything wrong with my code? Any help appreciated.
Thank you

```
  function arrayBreaker(arr) {
  let test = [];
  test.push(arguments[1]);
  test.push(arguments[2]);
  let target = arguments[0];

  target.filter(val => {
  if (test.indexOf(val) > -1) {
  target.splice(target.indexOf(val), 1);
  }
 });
  return target;
 }

console.log(arrayBreaker([1,2,3,4,5], 2, 3));
```

Comment: In `filter` you need to _return a truthy or falsy value_, not mutate the array.

Comment: As Xufox said u cannot mutate using `filter`, you want to use `.forEach` for such operations.

Comment: @imixtron: Is that what he said?

Comment: @imixtron Thank you for the info. I am still not able to get the right output with forEach. I just replaced the filter with forEach. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Aditya: `.forEach()` won't make a difference. What was meant in the first comment was that you return the result of the condition inside the `.filter` callback, and assign (or return) the resulting array. But do you actually need to mutate the original array?

Comment: @Aditya It’s `return target.filter(val => test.indexOf(val) > -1)`. No need for `forEach`, no need for `splice`, no need for `if` statements. Please read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: ...and why are you using the `arguments` object instead of parameter names?

Comment: @rock star Currently practising with arguments that's why testing with different scenarios and thank you.

Comment: @Xufox I was using splice to get rid of duplicate elements using if stat. Now I understand I am not supposed to use them in filter(). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.filter()` like a general purpose iterator, and mutating the array you're iterating, which causes problems because the iterator is unaware of the items you're removing.

If you need to mutate the original array, instead return the result of the `.indexOf()` operation from the `.filter()` callback, or better yet, use `.includes()` instead, and then copy the result into the original after first clearing it.

```js
function arrayBreaker(target, ...test) {
  const res = target.filter(val => !test.includes(val));
  target.length = 0;
  target.push(...res);
  return target;
}

console.log(arrayBreaker([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 3));
```

---

If you don't need to mutate, but can return a copy, then it's simpler.

```js
function arrayBreaker(target, ...test) {
  return target.filter(val => !test.includes(val));
}

console.log(arrayBreaker([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 3));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Above code is short and beautiful and that's what I was looking for! Again Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Array is returning a new array based on filter criteria, in this case you are checking index of test.  In the callback function is expecting a true if you want to keep the value, otherwise return false.  In your case you shouldn't slice the target inside filter callback, but rather:

```
function arrayBreaker(arr) {
  let test = [];
  test.push(arguments[1]);
  test.push(arguments[2]);
  let target = arguments[0];

  let newArray = target.filter(val => {
    if (test.indexOf(val) > -1) {
      // filter value out
      return false;
    }
    // keep the val inside new array
    return true;
  });
  return newArray;
}
console.log(arrayBreaker([1,2,3,4,5], 2, 3));
```

for more information about array filter, check documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Depending on your use case there are few things that I think would be helpful, first I would declare the function parameters so it's clear that arrayBreaker is expecting multiple arguments.  Secondly I would expect second param as an array since we are expecting multiple values.  Something like below:

```
function arrayBreaker(arr, filterValues) {
  return arr.filter(val => {
    if (filterValues.indexOf(val) > -1) return false;
    return true;
  })
}
console.log(arrayBreaker([1,2,3,4,5], [2, 3]));
```